# Use sub graph during main graph build in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a pre trained model in Keras that i wish to convert to Tensorflow. In this pre trained Keras net, some of the layers are actually defined as a sub model that takes as an input other layers from the main model in a few occasions (each occasion gets a different layer as an input) and produce the output by the same serial of internal layers actions.

Is it possible to create such sub graph in Tensorflow that gets a tensor from the main graph and returns an output the same principle as Keras using the sub model?

The sub graph that i have tried to implement, is built from `tf.placeholder` as the first layer defined according to the expected shape and dtype as its input tensors.

One of the attempts that were failed is trying to connect between the main graph and the sub graph as following:

```
main_graph_out, = tf.import_graph_def(main_graph, 
                                         return_elements=[layer_name_as_input_to_sub_graph]])

sub_graph_out, = tf.import_graph_def(submodel_graph, input_map={first_sub_graph_layer_name: main_graph_out},
                                         return_elements=[last_sub_graph_layer_name])
```

but this failed due to:
`ValueError: Requested return tensor 'P3' not found in graph def`

(P3 is the name of the main graph layer that i wish to input the subgraph)

would appreciate any kind of help...
thanks a lot.